# aspxgridview row command delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I want to aspxgridview delete that row in the row command.

```
protected void BootstrapGridView1_RowCommand(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewRowCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (e.CommandArgs.CommandName == "delete")
        {
           ROW DELETE CODE
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the [ASPxGridViewRowEventArgs.KeyValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewRowEventArgs_KeyValuetopic) property to get the row ID and then delete the specific record from the database. You must specify the KeyFieldName="keyfieldcolumnname" to get the key column value at the RowCommand event.

The [ASPxGridViewRowEventArgs.KeyValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewRowEventArgs_KeyValuetopic) property provides a capability to get an ID value by a key value.

Example:

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            KeyFieldName="ID"...

protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, ASPxGridViewRowCommandEventArgs e) {
    ASPxGridView grid = (ASPxGridView)sender;
    object id = e.KeyValue;
   //Delete record using data adapter or some other ORM 
   // Delete from users where userid=id

}
```

References:
[Fields value in ASPxGridView on Row Command](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q494995/fields-value-in-aspxgridview-on-row-command)
[ASPxGridView - How to implement CRUD operations with a custom data source](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18686/aspxgridview-how-to-implement-crud-operations-with-a-custom-data-source)
[CRUD Operation Using Stored Procedure In ASP.NET GridView Real Time](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-using-stored-procedure-in-asp-net-gridview-real-time/)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the row from datagridview does not affect the datatable in the database. You need to write a query to remove data from the database..

If you are using sql, mysql etc, try something like getting the primary key or any unique column on the link button event and implement a command to remove the row.

something like this in your click event to get the ID to pass to database

```
int MyID = int.Parse(yourDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

and the query to delete from the database

```
delete from MyTable
where p_Key = MyID;
```